# VideoWrite not writing

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a lot of videos. I want to turn these videos 90 degrees counterclockwise and rewrite them.
I'm trying to do it for just one video for now. I got video as output but the content of the video is blank(0 sec). I could not understand the reason.

Here is my code ;

```
int main()
{

std::string videoPath = "/home/fifty/eclipse-workspace/detect/20210112_165122_B827EBB01032.avi";

cv::VideoCapture cap(videoPath);

boost::filesystem::path finalStorageVideoPath = "/home/fifty/eclipse-workspace/testOfflineAITracking/out.avi";

int frameWidth = cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
int frameHeight = cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);

cv::VideoWriter video(finalStorageVideoPath.string(),
            cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('H', '2', '6', '4'), 10,
            cv::Size(frameWidth, frameHeight));

cv::Mat img;
ulong FrameIndex = 0;

if (cap.open(videoPath))
    {
        while (cap.isOpened())
        {
            cout << "index : " << FrameIndex << endl;
            cap >> img;

            if(!img.empty())
            {
                transpose(img, img);
                flip(img, img, 0);

                cv::imshow("RotatingVideo", img);
                cv::waitKey(100);

                FrameIndex++;
                video.write(img);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        cap.release();
        video.release();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "End" << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to resize your frame before writing.

```
cv::resize(img, img, cv::Size(frameWidth, frameHeight));
video.write(img);
```